# Angular Dart error message

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I was just working on chapter 6 of AngularDart tutorial (part 1, creating the edit recipe component) - so far I have copied the view component, and made sure I added all the relevant details to web/main.dart and have checked class names etc are okay but I can't find why the following error is being thrown:

```
Build error:
Transform _Serial on tutorial|test/main_test.dart threw error: The null object does not have a getter 'arguments'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'arguments'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart 42                             Object._noSuchMethod
dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart 45                             Object.noSuchMethod
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 188         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass.<fn>.<fn>
dart:collection/list.dart 63                                     Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 180         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass.<fn>
dart:collection/list.dart 63                                     Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 176         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 165         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._walkSuperclassChain
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 156         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration.<fn>
dart:collection/list.dart 63                                     Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 120         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 3494                     ClassDeclaration.accept
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 19457                    NodeList.accept
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 4261                     CompilationUnit.visitChildren
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 14170                    RecursiveAstVisitor.visitCompilationUnit
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 4211                     CompilationUnit.accept
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 207         DirectiveMetadataCollectingVisitor.call
dart:core/iterable.dart 217                                      Iterable.forEach
package:angular/tools/transformer/expression_generator.dart 155  _LibrarySourceCrawler.crawl
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 27          SourceMetadataExtractor.gatherDirectiveInfo
package:angular/tools/transformer/expression_generator.dart 43   ExpressionGenerator.applyResolver
package:code_transformers/src/resolvers.dart 113                 Transformer&ResolverTransformer.applyToEntryPoints.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async/future.dart 118                                       Future.Future.<fn>
dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart 16                             Timer._createTimer.<fn>
dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 385                           _Timer._runTimers
dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 414                           _Timer._handleMessage
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 148                        _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage

dart:core                                                        Object.noSuchMethod
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 188         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass.<fn>.<fn>
dart:collection                                                  Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 180         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass.<fn>
dart:collection                                                  Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 176         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 165         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._walkSuperclassChain
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 156         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration.<fn>
dart:collection                                                  Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 120         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 3494                     ClassDeclaration.accept
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 19457                    NodeList.accept
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 4261                     CompilationUnit.visitChildren
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 14170                    RecursiveAstVisitor.visitCompilationUnit
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 4211                     CompilationUnit.accept
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 207         DirectiveMetadataCollectingVisitor.call
dart:core                                                        Iterable.forEach
package:angular/tools/transformer/expression_generator.dart 155  _LibrarySourceCrawler.crawl
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 27          SourceMetadataExtractor.gatherDirectiveInfo
package:angular/tools/transformer/expression_generator.dart 43   ExpressionGenerator.applyResolver
package:code_transformers/src/resolvers.dart 113                 Transformer&ResolverTransformer.applyToEntryPoints.<fn>.<fn>

Build error:
Transform _Serial on tutorial|web/main.dart threw error: The null object does not have a getter 'arguments'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'arguments'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart 42                             Object._noSuchMethod
dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart 45                             Object.noSuchMethod
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 188         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass.<fn>.<fn>
dart:collection/list.dart 63                                     Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 180         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass.<fn>
dart:collection/list.dart 63                                     Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 176         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 165         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._walkSuperclassChain
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 156         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration.<fn>
dart:collection/list.dart 63                                     Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 120         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 3494                     ClassDeclaration.accept
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 19457                    NodeList.accept
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 4261                     CompilationUnit.visitChildren
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 14170                    RecursiveAstVisitor.visitCompilationUnit
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 4211                     CompilationUnit.accept
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 207         DirectiveMetadataCollectingVisitor.call
dart:core/iterable.dart 217                                      Iterable.forEach
package:angular/tools/transformer/expression_generator.dart 155  _LibrarySourceCrawler.crawl
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 27          SourceMetadataExtractor.gatherDirectiveInfo
package:angular/tools/transformer/expression_generator.dart 43   ExpressionGenerator.applyResolver
package:code_transformers/src/resolvers.dart 113                 Transformer&ResolverTransformer.applyToEntryPoints.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async/future.dart 118                                       Future.Future.<fn>
dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart 16                             Timer._createTimer.<fn>
dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 385                           _Timer._runTimers
dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 414                           _Timer._handleMessage
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 148                        _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage

dart:core                                                        Object.noSuchMethod
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 188         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass.<fn>.<fn>
dart:collection                                                  Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 180         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass.<fn>
dart:collection                                                  Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 176         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._extractMappingsFromClass
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 165         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor._walkSuperclassChain
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 156         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration.<fn>
dart:collection                                                  Object&ListMixin.forEach
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 120         DirectiveMetadataCollectingAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 3494                     ClassDeclaration.accept
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 19457                    NodeList.accept
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 4261                     CompilationUnit.visitChildren
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 14170                    RecursiveAstVisitor.visitCompilationUnit
package:analyzer/src/generated/ast.dart 4211                     CompilationUnit.accept
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 207         DirectiveMetadataCollectingVisitor.call
dart:core                                                        Iterable.forEach
package:angular/tools/transformer/expression_generator.dart 155  _LibrarySourceCrawler.crawl
package:angular/tools/source_metadata_extractor.dart 27          SourceMetadataExtractor.gatherDirectiveInfo
package:angular/tools/transformer/expression_generator.dart 43   ExpressionGenerator.applyResolver
package:code_transformers/src/resolvers.dart 113                 Transformer&ResolverTransformer.applyToEntryPoints.<fn>.<fn>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: How does the code look like that produces this error? Can you please make the reference to the tutorial a link.

Comment: Do you still get this error with recent versions?